# how to run 'color' command in NAnt script

Tags: command-line, colors, nant

I've just started using Nant for my builds and tests. I want to make it change the color (or background) of my command prompt text when it fails so its easily noticed.

The command in command prompt on Windows is 'color 4' to change it to red and color 7 for back to white.

How do I make this run in a build script, echo doesn't work, exec doesn't work (may be using exec wrong though). I'd prefer to not have to run perl etc just to do something which is easily done in a standard command prompt window.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a custom task. If the task is included in the nant-file you'll not have any external dependency.

```
<project >

    <target name="color">
        <consolecolor color="Red" backgroundcolor="White"/>
        <echo message="red text"/>
        <consolecolor color="White" backgroundcolor="Black"/>
        <echo message="white text"/>
    </target>

    <script language="C#">
        <code>
            [TaskName("consolecolor")]
            public class TestTask : Task
            {
            private string _color;
            private string _backgroundColor;

            [TaskAttribute("color",Required=true)]
            public string Color
            {
            get { return _color; }
            set { _color = value; }
            }

            [TaskAttribute("backgroundcolor",Required=false)]
            public string BackgroundColor
            {
            get { return _backgroundColor; }
            set { _backgroundColor = value; }
            }

            protected override void ExecuteTask()
            {
            System.Console.ForegroundColor = (System.ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(System.ConsoleColor),Color);
            System.Console.BackgroundColor = (System.ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(System.ConsoleColor),BackgroundColor);
            }
            }
        </code>
    </script>

</project>
```

Comment: After setting the background color, you can add try{System.Console.Clear();}catch(){}.  1. This will clear the screen and set the entire background to the same color. You can see at a glance if the build failed.  2. The catch is to handle when the batch file is redirected.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up to my comment on the post by @Martin-Vobr:

I have added additional logic to properly change the background.  This will allow a build to be initiated in a command window, then progress can be checked at a glance.  I use a blue background for "building", green for "Success" and red for "Failure".

```
 <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446135/how-to-run-color-command-in-nant-script -->
  <!-- Sample:  <consolecolor color="Red" backgroundcolor="White"/> -->
  <!-- Alternative: http://riccardotramma.com/2011/05/nantcolours-v1-0-a-task-library-for-output-colouring-in-nant/ -->
  <script language="C#">
        <code>
        <![CDATA[
             [TaskName("consolecolor")]
            public class TestTask : Task
            {
                private string _color;
                private string _backgroundColor;

                [TaskAttribute("color",Required=true)]
                public string Color
                {
                    get { return _color; }
                    set { _color = value; }
                }

                [TaskAttribute("backgroundcolor",Required=false)]
                public string BackgroundColor
                {
                    get { return _backgroundColor; }
                    set { _backgroundColor = value; }
                }

                protected override void ExecuteTask()
                {
                    System.Console.ForegroundColor = (System.ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(System.ConsoleColor),Color);
                    System.Console.BackgroundColor = (System.ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(System.ConsoleColor),BackgroundColor);
                    // clearing the screen sets the entire screen to be the new color
                    ChangeColor((System.ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(System.ConsoleColor),Color), (System.ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(System.ConsoleColor),BackgroundColor));
                }

                // added by Brad Bruce
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460932/change-entire-console-background-color-win32-c

                [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
                static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputAttribute(IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
                   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out] ushort[] lpAttribute, uint nLength, COORD dwReadCoord,
                   out uint lpNumberOfAttrsRead);

                [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
                static extern bool FillConsoleOutputAttribute(IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
                   ushort wAttribute, uint nLength, COORD dwWriteCoord, out uint
                   lpNumberOfAttrsWritten);

                [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
                public struct COORD {
                    public short X;
                    public short Y;

                    public COORD(short X, short Y) {
                        this.X = X;
                        this.Y = Y;
                    }
                };

                [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
                 static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

                //C#: Get stdout handle
                const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
                const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
                const int STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12;
                //INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE //(return value if invalid handle is specified)

                // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_character_attributes

                public enum CharacterAttributes{
                    FOREGROUND_BLUE = 0x0001,
                    FOREGROUND_GREEN = 0x0002,
                    FOREGROUND_RED = 0x0004,
                    FOREGROUND_INTENSITY = 0x0008,
                    BACKGROUND_BLUE = 0x0010,
                    BACKGROUND_GREEN = 0x0020,
                    BACKGROUND_RED = 0x0040,
                    BACKGROUND_INTENSITY = 0x0080,
                    COMMON_LVB_LEADING_BYTE = 0x0100,
                    COMMON_LVB_TRAILING_BYTE = 0x0200,
                    COMMON_LVB_GRID_HORIZONTAL = 0x0400,
                    COMMON_LVB_GRID_LVERTICAL = 0x0800,
                    COMMON_LVB_GRID_RVERTICAL = 0x1000,
                    COMMON_LVB_REVERSE_VIDEO = 0x4000,
                    COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE = 0x8000
                }

                static void ChangeColor(System.ConsoleColor color, System.ConsoleColor backgroundColor) {
                    uint written = 0;
                    COORD writeCoord = new COORD(0, 0);
                    ushort[] attribute = new ushort[400];

                    IntPtr consoleOutputHandle = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

                    int consoleBufferWidth = Console.BufferWidth;
                    int consoleBufferLength = Console.BufferHeight;
                    //if (consoleBufferLength > Console.CursorTop) {
                    //    consoleBufferLength = Console.CursorTop;
                    //}

                    for (int y = 0; y < consoleBufferLength; y++)     // rows
                    {
                        writeCoord.X = (short)0;
                        writeCoord.Y = (short)y;
                        ReadConsoleOutputAttribute(consoleOutputHandle, attribute, (uint)consoleBufferWidth, writeCoord, out written);

                        for (int x2 = 0; x2 < consoleBufferWidth; x2++){  // columns
                            attribute[x2] &= 0xFF00;  // zero the background and foreground color
                            attribute[x2] |= (ushort)((((int)backgroundColor) << 4) | (int)color);
                        }
                        FillConsoleOutputAttribute(consoleOutputHandle, attribute[0], (uint)consoleBufferWidth, writeCoord, out written);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]> 
        </code>
    </script>
```